# How to Integrate DocuSign with your CodeIgniter web application using Postman?

Tags: php, codeigniter, postman, docusignapi, e-signature

I added docusign into my postman now i want to use the postman inside my codeignator web app how can i do that

```
composer require docusign/esign-client
```

not able to install this library

> C:\xampp\htdocs\affiniks_docusign-php>composer install
> 'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

> Problem 1
> - Installation request for docusign/esign-client v6.15.0-rc -> satisfiable by docusign/esign-client[v6.15.0-rc].
> - docusign/esign-client v6.15.0-rc requires php >=7.4 -> your PHP version (7.3.0) does not satisfy that requirement.    `

I updated my php version to 8.0.0 then it showed the below error

> In ProxyManager.php line 83:
>
> Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy url
>
> require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [...]

Comment: Postman is a testing tool, you don't integrate it into your application. In php you can use a library such as cURL or Guzzle to make equivalent http requests using code. In fact, if you have made successful requests using postman, it can automatically generate the equivalent php code for you for each http request.

Comment: But the actual error you've got doesn't seem particularly related to that: "malformed http_proxy url" suggests you have a setting somewhere with a bad URL in it. I don't know codeigniter specifically but perhaps you can google about this, or check your settings

Comment: https://malfariza45.medium.com/resolved-error-unable-to-use-proxy-url-http-proxy-formatted-incorrectly-in-composer-231f43f060fd     i solved the proxy issue and installed the guzzle library but still need a source code on how generate php code for calling the api

Comment: I already told you...you can use cURL or Guzzle. And if you've been using Postman already to test the API, it can auto-generate PHP code for you.

Comment: Of course there's also https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdks/php/ (which I found by just typing "docusign API PHP" into google). It contains some code examples to get you started. This is probably easier than writing your own HTTP requests using Guzzle (unless you have the aforementioned Postman examples ready to copy).  And if you need more examples, you could always try just typing [docusign php sdk examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=docusign+php+sdk+examples) into your favourite search engine! If you have a more _specific_ problem, you can ask that on stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks!@ADyson i did look up to this site and used the postman tool to test ,but i can barely understand the examples they are providing in it .Even i haven't worked with code igniter before so its taking up so much of my time to implement those in my source code

Comment: Ok. I don't actually think it being in codeigniter is really all that relevant as such - the basic process of making API requests is similar in all flavours of PHP. I suggest you first get used to using the Docusign PHP SDK. Make a separate application - either a basic web application (no framework), or a command-line PHP script, using the SDK, and make simple tests using the examples from the documentation - get your authentication process right using the examples, and then try simple requests to fetch data, etc. Once you're confident, then you can move onto integrating into codeigniter

Comment: Right now it's difficult for the stackoverflow community to give you any useful help because all we really know is that you are struggling somehow with something in the docusign API documentation. We don't have a clear, specific problem statement, or a concrete programming issue to resolve. We don't provide generic tutorials, or read documentation on your behalf. See the [ask] guide. If you get stuck on some particular aspect when you try your simple test application I suggest making a new Question in Stackoverflow about it, thens show your code and explain the specific issue or bug you've got

Comment: I did all of the things you mentioned i made 2 separate apps for testing,fetching,and requesting sign through api calls ,yet each app have a max. of 20 successful api calls which i used up yesterday.So if i need to test again i need to make a whole new app then repeat the same steps which they have shown in the documentation.And am new here and learning how to present my issue clearly.Thank you for noticing and taking your time to reply.

Comment: That limit is not something you can solve with PHP. There is documentation on the site about the rate limits etc, for example here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/rules-and-limits/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the easiest way for you to get going.
Download a [PHP quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) after you make sure you created your [DocuSign Developer account](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/account/).
This will download a ZIP file with pre-configured code that is just for your account with all the needed auth configuration and you can just run it on your machine.

Then, take that and change it or move it to your own solution or project after you know it's working.